# How do I create a mask in python?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor, masking

I'm writing a script for some transition effects in Blender in the VSE. Currently I'm trying to have the script create a mask that can be used. I call `bpy.ops.mask.new()` but get *"context is incorrect"* error. Makes sense since I'm in the VSE, but does anyone know how I can set the context to the CLIP_EDITOR or another more preferred way to be able to simply create a mask I can work with? Thanks in advance for the help!